# TypeError: League\Flysystem\AwsS3V3\AwsS3V3Adapter::__construct(): Argument #2 ($bucket) must be of type string

Tags: php, laravel, bitbucket, pipeline

I was trying to set up Bitbucket pipeline for mine Laravel repo, but on 'testing' step while trying to add image to AWS bucket I get

```
TypeError:League\Flysystem\AwsS3V3\AwsS3V3Adapter::__construct() Argument #2 ($bucket) must be of type string, null given
```

I already tried to run pipeline from different php images: php:8.1-fpm, php:8.1-apache, php:8.1-alpine, even from composer:2.3.5 image. Here is the alpine pipeline:

```
image: php:8.1.4-alpine


pipelines:
  branches:
    development:
      - step:
          name: test
          script:
            - apk add --no-cache bash git zip curl libjpeg-turbo-dev freetype-dev libmcrypt-dev libjpeg libpng-dev libzip-dev unzip && docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-jpeg --with-freetype &&  docker-php-ext-configure zip && docker-php-ext-install gd && docker-php-ext-install zip && curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer && composer install && php artisan test
          caches:
            - composer
      - step:
          name: deploy-dev
          deployment: production
          caches:
            - composer
          script:
            - composer global require "laravel/envoy"
            - ~/.composer/vendor/bin/envoy run deploy-dev
```

Here is full error code:

```
TypeError: League\Flysystem\AwsS3V3\AwsS3V3Adapter::__construct(): Argument #2 ($bucket) must be of type string, null given, called in /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/FilesystemManager.php on line 245 and defined in /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/vendor/league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3/AwsS3V3Adapter.php:120
  Stack trace:
  #0 /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/FilesystemManager.php(245): League\Flysystem\AwsS3V3\AwsS3V3Adapter->__construct(Object(Aws\S3\S3Client), NULL, 'conversations', Object(League\Flysystem\AwsS3V3\PortableVisibilityConverter), NULL, Array, false)
  #1 /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/FilesystemManager.php(149): Illuminate\Filesystem\FilesystemManager->createS3Driver(Array)
  #2 /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/FilesystemManager.php(117): Illuminate\Filesystem\FilesystemManager->resolve('s3')
  #3 /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/FilesystemManager.php(80): Illuminate\Filesystem\FilesystemManager->get('conversationsPu...')
  #4 /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Facade.php(337): Illuminate\Filesystem\FilesystemManager->disk('conversationsPu...')
  #5 /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/Modules/ClientAPI/Http/Controllers/Conversations/ConversationMessagesController.php(51): Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade::__callStatic('disk', Array)
  #6 /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Controller.php(54): Modules\ClientAPI\Http\Controllers\Conversations\ConversationMessagesController->createImage(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Modules\ClientAPI\Entities\Conversation))
  #7 /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/ControllerDispatcher.php(45): Illuminate\Routing\Controller->callAction('createImage', Array)
  #8 /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php(261): Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route), Object(Modules\ClientAPI\Http\Controllers\Conversations\ConversationMessagesController), 'createImage')
  #9 /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php(204): Illuminate\Routing\Route->runController()
  #10 /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(725): Illuminate\Routing\Route->run()
  #11 /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(141): Illuminate\Routing\Router->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
  #12 /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/Modules/ClientAPI/Http/Middleware/ValidateConversationMiddleware.php(29): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
  #13 /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(180): Modules\ClientAPI\Http\Middleware\ValidateConversationMiddleware->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
  #14 /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Middleware/SubstituteBindings.php(50): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
  #15 /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
  #16 /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Middleware/ThrottleRequests.php(126): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
  #17 /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Middleware/ThrottleRequests.php(102): Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests->handleRequest(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure), Array)
  #18 /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Middleware/ThrottleRequests.php(54): Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests->handleRequestUsingNamedLimiter(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure), 'api', Object(Closure))
  #19 /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure), 'api')
  #20 /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/Middleware/Authenticate.php(44): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
  #21 /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure), 'sanctum')
  #22 /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(116): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
  #23 /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(726): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
  #24 /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(703): Illuminate\Routing\Router->runRouteWithinStack(Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
  #25 /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(667): Illuminate\Routing\Router->runRoute(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route))
  #26 /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(656): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatchToRoute(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
  #27 /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(167): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
  #28 /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(141): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
  #29 /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php(21): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
  #30 /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/ConvertEmptyStringsToNull.php(31): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TransformsRequest->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
  #31 /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
  #32 /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php(21): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
  #33 /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TrimStrings.php(40): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TransformsRequest->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
  #34 /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
  #35 /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/ValidatePostSize.php(27): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
  #36 /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
  #37 /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance.php(86): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
  #38 /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
  #39 /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/vendor/fruitcake/laravel-cors/src/HandleCors.php(52): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
  #40 /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(180): Fruitcake\Cors\HandleCors->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
  #41 /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Http/Middleware/TrustProxies.php(39): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
  #42 /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
  #43 /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(116): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
  #44 /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(142): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
  #45 /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(111): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
  #46 /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/Concerns/MakesHttpRequests.php(526): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
  #47 /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/Concerns/MakesHttpRequests.php(321): Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase->call('POST', '/api/v1/convers...', Array, Array, Array, Array)
  #48 /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/Modules/ClientAPI/Tests/Feature/Conversations/Messages/CreateTest.php(58): Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase->post('/api/v1/convers...', Array)
  #49 /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestCase.php(1545): Modules\ClientAPI\Tests\Feature\Conversations\Messages\CreateTest->testCreateImage200()
  #50 /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestCase.php(1151): PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase->runTest()
  #51 /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestResult.php(726): PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase->runBare()
  #52 /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestCase.php(903): PHPUnit\Framework\TestResult->run(Object(Modules\ClientAPI\Tests\Feature\Conversations\Messages\CreateTest))
  #53 /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestSuite.php(677): PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase->run(Object(PHPUnit\Framework\TestResult))
  #54 /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestSuite.php(677): PHPUnit\Framework\TestSuite->run(Object(PHPUnit\Framework\TestResult))
  #55 /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestSuite.php(677): PHPUnit\Framework\TestSuite->run(Object(PHPUnit\Framework\TestResult))
  #56 /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/TextUI/TestRunner.php(673): PHPUnit\Framework\TestSuite->run(Object(PHPUnit\Framework\TestResult))
  #57 /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/TextUI/Command.php(143): PHPUnit\TextUI\TestRunner->run(Object(PHPUnit\Framework\TestSuite), Array, Array, true)
  #58 /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/TextUI/Command.php(96): PHPUnit\TextUI\Command->run(Array, true)
  #59 /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit(98): PHPUnit\TextUI\Command::main()
  #60 {main}
```

Here is my composer requirements that may cause error:

```
 "require": {
        "php": "^8.1",
        "doctrine/dbal": "^3.3",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.0.1",
        "laravel/framework": "^9.0",
        "laravel/sanctum": "^2.14",
        "laravel/scout": "^9.4",
        "laravel/socialite": "^5.5",
        "league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3": "^3.0",
        ....
    },
```

Comment: But why are your test calling an s3 bucket? that should be mocked

Comment: It puts 'UploadedFile::fake()->image('document.jpg')' in the on the was bucket in order to test if everything is configured properly. On local machine it works fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to run `composer require league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3 "^3.0" --with-all-dependencies` cannot just add the single package into your composer.json you need the "dependencies" for the package that installed with `--with-all-dependencies`